# Domain name is bringing up wrong site

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, website

I have a VPS that hosts several domains. I have set up Apache in the following manner:

First VirtualHost

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/somedomain.com`

```
<VirtualHost somedomain.com:80>
    ServerName somedomain.com
    ServerAlias www.somedomain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Second VirtualHost

`/etc/apache2/sites-available/someotherdomain.com`

```
<VirtualHost someotherdomain.com:80>
    ServerName someotherdomain.com
    ServerAlias www.someotherdomain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I symlink the config files from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled` and all is well.

I had a need to 'turn off' `someotherdomain.com`, so I removed the symlink to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/someotherdomain.com` from `sites-enabled` and the site no longer shows up... BUT typing `someotherdomain.com` into a web browser brings up `somedomain.com`!!! I need it to not resolve at all.

Does somethiing need to be done in the VirtualHost to just automatically return a 500 or something along those lines. I really don't want people to reach one website from a different domain.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

`ports.conf` looks like this

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:443
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did you reload Apache?

Comment: You mean `sudo service apache2 restart`? Yes, several times. Even did a server reboot or two since I made these changes.

Comment: I am assuming this is Ubuntu/Debian?  What does your /etc/apache2/ports.conf look like?  Do you have an appropriate Listen and NameVirtualHost options set?  Also, IMO you should be using the IP in your `<VirtualHost ...:80>` blocks rather than the name.

Comment: Edited to add ports.conf

Comment: OK, so what changes did you make to the DNS records for the domain being moved?

Comment: It's not being 'moved' per se. I just needed to turn it off. My A record still points to the server IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want it to resolve at all, you need to delete the host from DNS.

Otherwise Apache will deliver the first vhost instead and you can't turn this off.  To prevent this, you need to configure either a dummy vhost with e.g. just a blank `index.html` or configure it to deliver an error message (e.g. `404`).

Comment: That makes perfect sense! I was hoping that if Apache couldn't match the request to a VirtualHost it would simply ignore it. There's no way to make that happen?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I am not sure why as this is a quite common problem.

Comment: I just changed the VirtualHost directives to point to a 'maintenance' type page and re-symlinked them. After restarting Apache, it went right to that page. Thanks!!